# Scale automatically by monitoring the load in app server

Tags: haproxy, django, scalability

I have a regular setup with 4 droplets in DigitalOcean. One for Haproxy as load balancer, two for app servers, run same Django application and one for database.

It's quite easy to add another app server manually, however, what I really want is to create a new droplet(machine) automatically if any peak occurs.

How can I monitor the load in app servers and create a new one if some threshold is exceed automatically?

Comment: you don't monitor for load in app servers; you check how much one app droplet can handle; and monitor on haproxy if certain threshold of traffic is being sent to app droplet. If above threshold then using digital ocean API you spin up new droplet with app and add it to your haproxy backend.

Comment: That's elegant solution. But how can I do it automatically? Basically, I may set max # of droplets and system decides creates/drops droplets. I may implement such system but I just wonder is there any ready-to-use solution?

Comment: if there is any such solution, I'm not aware of it, and Google does not seem to have anything useful either from the looks after few min of searching :\

Comment: Yup I couldn't find any solution either. Does AWS offer such solution?

Comment: I've never used AWS :\ can't say ...

Comment: Hello I know it's an old question but digitalocean has an article on this. I just want to provide it for future users coming here. https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/horizontally-scaling-php-applications/ It is on scaling php applications though the principle is the same.